# Raspberry pi 4 power supply without any periphirals

Tags: pi-4, power-supply

I'm planning to use raspberry pi 4 for homebridge. I will not be connecting any display or any input device and will use ethernet cable for network. will 5v 2amp adapter be sufficient for power?

Answer (score 4):

A display or input device will generally consume negligible power so are irrelevant.

The Foundation has various [recommendations](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/#pi-power), but lists "Typical bare-board active current consumption" as 600mA, so a quality 2A supply should easily run the Pi4.

See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)